# Python Azure Function remote debugging

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, remote-debugging

Is there any way, with any IDE or tool, to remotely debug a Python Azure Function?

It is possible to run a [local emulator and use a debugger with VS Code](https://www.sqlshack.com/deploy-python-apps-to-azure-functions-using-visual-studio-code/), but my requirement is to attach a debugger to a published Function.

This can be done [for the .NET runtime using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/296869/how-to-remote-debugg-an-azure-function-that-we-tri.html), but I found no reference stating how to achieve the same in Python.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Under configuration and general settings in our Azure Function App, we have an option to enable remote debugger.

[image]

After publishing the function, we can attach the debugger from Visual Studio.

Have a look on the [blog](https://blog.krishkothapalli.com/guides/remote-debug-your-azure-function-app-v2-in-visual-studio-2019) to check the process for attaching the debugger and interacting with Cloud Explorer.

Also, we can achieve this from PyCharm IDE as well. For more insights refer to these [steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html).

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this does not solve my issue. As far as I know, with Visual Studio you can remotely debug a function written in .NET, not Python. And with PyCharm, following the tutorial, I was unable to attach the debugget to the Function itself. Could you provide some guidance in order to do so?